# Format specifier for scanning long unsigned int

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to take two variables as input using this code snippet:-

```
unsigned int i;

unsigned long int j;

scanf("%u",i);

scanf("%lu",j);
```

But this give rise to the following warnings :-

warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
warning: format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
Can anyone explain to me whats happening here?

Answer (score 23):

You need to add a leading `&`, as `scanf` takes *pointers* to the output parameters. Otherwise, it can not write to them.

```
scanf("%lu", &i);
```